# Prime number inequality

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Hey I recently got interested in number theory and proved the following inequality:

\begin{align}
    x^m-y^m >  p_n^2 + 4p_n + 3 > 1\ \text{(corrected again)}                   
  \end{align}

where 
$x-y\neq1$ and m in an integer >1

and

\begin{align}
\gcd(x,y)&=1  \\
    xy&= 2*3*5*..*p_n                         
  \end{align}

So my question is ... Does this formula already exist? And is it useful or slightly interesting?

Comment: Presumably you also assume $x>y$?

Comment: I thought that was self implied as x^m>y^m+1 ... so x^m>y^m hence, x>y

Comment: No, this is not _self implied_! You write $x-y \ne 1$.

Comment: well I say g.c.d (x,y) =1 ... Hence x and y must be integers

Comment: yes ... it is necessary for them to be integers (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: @Jyrki: Your $A(n)$ is IMO the primorial function $\#p_n$ and the asymptotic growth rate is $\#p_n \approx e^{\#p_n}$, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html formula (4).

Comment: Thanks @gammatester, I was just looking at that page :-) I think that for large $n$ we get something stronger out of that.

Comment: @Anant: There was no confusion! I am just trying to prove a stronger inequality (asymptotically) that is valid, irrespective of whether $x$ and $y$ are integers or not.

Comment: Here's a link to the pdf(readable) version of the argument used dropbox.com/s/aua4d2a96d225wn/prime%20numbers.pdf

Comment: sry for the terrible formatting ... will edit (if asked)

Comment: Would it be possible to format this using LaTeX to make it easier to read?

Comment: Added a few TeX-commands. Take a look. You will be needing them here in the future :-)

Comment: Umm ... can anyone give me a quick Latex tutorial link?

Comment: Since I am horrible at latex I have done the above in a pdf document available here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aua4d2a96d225wn/prime%20numbers.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The inequality deals with the primorial function
$$
p_n\#=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots p_n=\prod_{p\le p_n,\ p\in \mathbb{P}}p,
$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.
[Asymptotically we have the result](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html) that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln p_n\#}{p_n}=1.
$$
Early on the primorials are bit smaller though. For example $\ln(59\#)\approx49$.

Consider the following problem. Assume that $xy=p_n\#$ and that $x-y\ge3$ (in OP $x,y$ were constrained to be integers of opposite parity such that $x-y>1$ implying that $x-y\ge 3$). Therefore
$$x^m-y^m\ge x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)\ge3(x+y).$$
Here by the AM-GM inequality $x+y\ge2\sqrt{xy}=2\sqrt{p_n\#}.$ Therefore asymptotically we get a lower bound
$$
x^m-y^m\ge 6\sqrt{p_n\#}\ge6e^{\frac n2(1+o(1))}.
$$

Asymptotically we also have have $p_n\approx n\ln n.$ This suggests that
$$
\frac{\ln(x^m-y^m)}{\ln p_n}\ge \frac n{2\ln n} K(n),
$$
where $K(n)$ is some correction factor (bounded away from zero) that I won't calculate.

Your result says (using only the main term $p_n^2$) that
$$
\frac{\ln(x^m-y^m)}{\ln p_n}\ge 2.
$$
So asymptotically it is weaker. But it would not be fair to call your result trivial because of this. I'm not a number theorist, but I have seen simpler estimates being derived in many number theory books, and in addition to being fun, they pave the road to stronger results.

Please share details of your argument with us, so that we can comment and give you other kind of feedback!

Comment: Asymptotically it is, of course, irrelevant whether I require $x-y\ge1$ or $x-y\ge3$ here.

Comment: this is gonna b a long story

Comment: @Anant: I think you can answer your own question also. Then you won't be constrained by the 500 character limit.

Comment: Sorry about the bad mistakes in the definitions. They were a result of earlier editing, where I tried to avoid using subscripts on primes.

Comment: Does $ \ln p_n \# < p_n $ always hold? If so, where can a proof be found?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: I'm not a number theorist. The [mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html) I linked to seems to have some references. I would start there.

Comment: I see, thank you. Unfortunately it seems they deal with $\vartheta(x)= \sum_{p\le x} \ln p$, where $x$ is real. I'll search.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo small values of $n,$ you do not need to assume that $x-y\ne 1$ as well as asymptotic on the primorial function. Instead, you can get away with Bertrand's postulate stating that $p_{n}<2p_{n-1}$ or $p_{n-1}\ge p_n/2.$ Indeed, if $m\ge 2,$ then 
$$x^m-y^m=(x-y)(x^{m-1}+...+y^{m-1})\ge (x-y)(x+y)\ge x+y\ge 2\sqrt{xy}.$$
Note, $$2\sqrt{xy}=2\sqrt{p_1...p_{n-3}p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_n}$$ and using the fact that $p_{n-2}\ge p_n/4,$ $p_{n-3}\ge p_n/8$ and $p_{n-1}\ge p_n/2$ we can estimate
$2\sqrt{xy}\ge 2\sqrt{p_1p_2\cdot...\frac{p_n^4}{64}}=\frac{p_n^2}{8}\sqrt{p_1p_2...}.$ So we are left to check the result for small values of $p_n.$